# Prolog "findall/3" does not return a list

Tags: prolog

I am struggling to understand why findall/3 behaves as such in my program. Basically I have wrote I predicate ,
that is supposed to take a list , and return each possible couple of indexes for instance if my list has length 3,
`pairs([1,2,3],L)` will return
`[1/2, 1/3, 2/3]` which is a list as I expected.( inside my pairs predicate i generate this list L with findall )
But I have wrote another predicate, that's supposed to return me a list with all the sublists , of a list and the predicate also uses findall, but the result is not what I expected.

```
/*calculate a list CASES with all the sublists from LIST .*/
test(LIST, CASES):-
   pairs(LIST, L),
   member(X/Y, L),  
   findall(SUBLIST, sublist(LIST, X, Y,  SUBLIST), CASES).
```

and the result is something like that (I had to press `;` to generate all results).

```
[[1, 2]]    
[[1, 2, 3]] 
[[2, 3]]
```

why results from findall do not come with a list?

Comment: `member(X/Y, L)` has three solutions in your case...

Comment: I got it you mean, that I have wrote, for each member findall .. but for each member (couple of indexes) there is only one sublist.

Comment: is there a way to put all the sublists, in a LIST with a builtin predicate or I should use some form of append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `findall(SUBLIST, sublist(LIST, X, Y,  SUBLIST), CASES)` is evaluated X and Y are already bound to values. For `sublist([1, 2, 3], 1, 2,  SUBLIST)`, there is exactly one solution (`[1, 2]`), which findall returns in a list.

When you backtrack, X and Y get assigned different values and findall is evaluated again, leading to a different single result.

You have to move the member call inside the findall

```
test(LIST, CASES):-
   pairs(LIST, L), 
   findall(SUBLIST, (member(X/Y, L), sublist(LIST, X, Y,  SUBLIST)), CASES).
```

(I'm not entirely sure about the syntax anymore, but it was something like this)

Comment: thank you so much , I wanted to say that but I did not know that i can include 2 statements in the second argument of findall.

Comment: @brucebanner if this solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: i am sorry , I waneed to do so immediately, but the site told me I had to after some minutes and I got distracted and forgot about it! you did well to remind me of!